# 'user' is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
'id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'name' varchar(75) NOT NULL,
'password' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
'email' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE KEY 'email' ('email')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

[image: D]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use quotes for the names of objects / entities, that stringifies it as a value instead. This would be the correct syntax you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY email (email) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!

Comment: Use backtics (\`) around table and column names, at least when there is a conflict with reserved words.

Comment: @XeroDay Sure thing no problem! Please see Rick James' helpful comment as well. 